# Not able to load google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation

I am trying to show the user's location obtained using geolocation API on google map.but the map is not loading.What am i doing wrong ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    trackLocation()
})

//Track the user's location with high accuracy
function trackLocation(){
    if(navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            successFunction,
            errorFunction,
            {enableHighAccuracy : true,
             timeout:1000 * 10 * 100,
             maximumAge:0
            }
        )
    }
}

function successFunction(position){
    plotMap(position)  
}

function errorFunction(error){
    alert(error)
}

function plotMap(position){
    var location = new  google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
            position.coords.longitude)
    alert('created locaction')
    var plotOptions = {
        center: location,
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    alert('created options')
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),plotOptions)
    alert('created map')
}
```

and the html is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{STATIC_URL}}jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{STATIC_URL}}javascript_posted_above.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
</head>
<body>
    Hi
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which, if any, of your alerts are being called?

Comment: all of them are being called.

Comment: do you see any errors in the console? Maybe you are using browser which doesn't support google maps or geolocation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qy7Wt/1/). The only differences between this and yours are the removal of the static js references and added the CSS. Without that CSS the map doesn't appear to display. I have never experienced this problem when using the Maps Api, perhaps I just added this CSS without thinking.

The CSS was taken from the [HelloWorld tutorial](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html#HelloWorld) on the docs.

Comment: Thomas Nadin , Yes its indeed the css issue works for me too once i include the css, But i am not able to understand why is that so?Sorry i am not n00b :(

Comment: Based on @Luuk's answer I would have to make a guess that when the parent's width of the map is undefined or vague there appears to be an issue, but this is just an assumption.

Answer (score 1):

here is [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7BLj5/3/), I changed a few things:

- First off all, I changed Alert to Console.log, which is important
  since it is a non-obstructive way of logging, alert stops script
  excecution and is not reliable.
- I removed the google map script tag, and dynamically added it to the page in the document.ready handler, I also added a callback function *"&callback=trackLocation"*, the JSON-P loaded script from Google will run the function with that name, when its executed.
- I attached the function trackLocation(), directly to the window object, so it would be found by the script loaded from Google.
- I changed the height of your map_canvas to 500px, instead of 100%, there seems to be an issue stretching a map. My first google search gave me: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/google-map-not-stretching-properly-when-width-set-to-100 you could do more research with that.

Good luck with your map!

Comment: Thanks luuk I'll keep the guidelines in my while working with javascript.The isue seems to be that I've not included the css given in the example.Though I am not able to understand why not including the css makes it behave in such a way.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried calling googlemap.js before your .js in the html?

Comment: rebelbass since i am doing all the stuff in my.js file after the document load this this should not create a difference , I tested doing that on your suggestion this doesn't make a difference.Thanks for the suggestion though :)

Answer (score 0):

I was loading the Google Maps API like this:

```
function mapsjsready()
{
    // mapsjs ready!
}
$(document).ready( function() {
    var mapsjs = document.createElement( 'script' );
    mapsjs.type    = "text/javascript";
    mapsjs.async   = true;
    mapsjs.src     = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false";
    mapsjs.id      = "mapsjs";
    mapsjs.onload = mapsjsready;
    // Only for IE 6 and 7
    mapsjs.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if( this.readyState == 'complete' )
        {
            mapsjsready();
        }
    }
    document.body.appendChild( mapsjs );
});
```

But it suddenly stopped working.

I found that adding the callback parameter somehow solved the problem :

```
function mapsjsready()
{
    // mapsjs ready!
}
function mapsjsloaded()
{
    // mapsjs loaded!
}
$(document).ready( function() {
    var mapsjs = document.createElement( 'script' );
    mapsjs.type    = "text/javascript";
    mapsjs.async   = true;
    mapsjs.src     = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=mapsjsloaded";
    mapsjs.id      = "mapsjs";
    mapsjs.onload = mapsjsready;
    // Only for IE 6 and 7
    mapsjs.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if( this.readyState == 'complete' )
        {
            mapsjsready();
        }
    }
    document.body.appendChild( mapsjs );
});
```

I don't understand why, but adding the callback parameter solved my problem.